# Writing testable code when new object is being constructed using Mockito only

Tags: java, testing, mockito

So I am writing a class which I want to follow the best practices and be testable.
I have a new object to be created inside it. So, I am following the factory pattern to achieve it.

```
public class Apple {
    // factory object injected in class
    private SeedFactory seedFactory; 

    // Method to be tested 
    public void myMethod(String property1, int property2, String depends) { 
        // Just to set the necessary parameter
        seedFactory = new SeedFactory(property1, property2); 
        // Factory pattern intact. Instance generation depends on only one parameter
        SeedFactory result = seedFactory.getInstance(depends); 
    }
}
```

EDIT: Adding code for factory as well.

```
public class SeedFactory{
String property1;
int property2;

SeedFactory(property1,property2){
this.property1 = property1;
this.property2 = property2;
}
SeedFactory getInstance(int depends){
if(depends == 1)
{ // do stuff }
else{ // do stuff and return instance }
```

Now, before I actually create the new object, I have to make sure that I set two properties for the new instance to be generated, which are needed to be present irrespective of the type of instance generated by the factory. `depends` is the actual parameter which tells the factory what instance to return.

Now, as far as testability of this code is concerned, I can user `PowerMockito` to mock the factory object using `whenNew` but using PowerMockito is not a choice. I have to make it testable without it.

Also, I have tried to encapsulate the `new` call within a one line function and then use `spy`. But I want to avoid using `spy`, since it is not considered a good practice, in context of where this code is being used as a whole.

So my question is, Is there any way, without using PowerMockito, to re-write this class so that it can be unit tested properly?

If the instance to be generated needed only one parameter, then it would have been trivial. However, I don't want to pass more than one parameter to `getInstance()`.

Comment: `seedFactory` is the one I need to mock and inject.

Comment: It sounds like you actually want to inject a SeedFactoryFactory.

Comment: BTW, it's considered a best practice in Java to capitalize the name of a class.

Comment: I find this code confusing. You need 3 properties to build a valid/useful SeedFactory instance, so you create an invalid/non-useful instance (a potential source of bugs) with 2 properties and use it (as a SeedFactoryFactory, as David Wallace pointed out) to create a valid instance with a 3rd property. Why not have a constructor with 3 properties or use the builder pattern to add all the needed properties one by one?  Also, you don't do anything with `result` - I assume that's an edit for brevity, but it makes it less clear what you really need to mock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SeedFactory` is not Apple's dependancy but your method depends on `SeedFactory` which has "uses" relationship. So to define proper relation i would suggest you use "USES" relation as below:

```
public void myMethod(SeedFactory seedFactory, String depends){ // Method to be tested
```

Now you could mock `SeedFactory` and can unit test it appropriately.

Comment: So where exactly do I construct the passed `seedFactory` ?

Comment: One level top. Whoever is the consumer of myMethod.

Comment: sorry but I didn't quite get your point, so I have added the definition of the factory. Please see the edits. Now, the consumer of the method needs to directly call the constructor of the factory on its own?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing something wrong.

If `SeedFactory` isn't an `Apple`'s dependency but an internal concern, hence you don't need to mock a `SeedFactory` to test `Apple`. You should test the public API provided by Apple only.

If `SeedFactory` is an `Apple`'s dependency, so it definitely should be injected.